# Count of span tags below div with no id using jQuery

Tags: jquery, count

Below is a screen shot of html containing two lists of span tags under nested div tags.  Both sets of span lists are identical.  How do I get the count of span tags of one or the other?  Notice that only the top most div has an id.  I can't rely on jQuery("#resultsContainer span").length because I'll get the total span tags in the entire container.

[image]

=====================

## 2/24/2012 - final answer

```
long pageCountText = (long)Element.GetLongValueFromJQuery(driver, "$('#resultsContainer .pagination').first().children('span').length");

public static long GetLongValueFromJQuery(IWebDriver driver, string jQueryCode)
{
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
    return (long)js.ExecuteScript("return " + jQueryCode);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery("#resultsContainer > .pagination").first().children("span").length
```

will give you the count of the first collection.

Comment: I'll give you the point since I had to keep this in a single line because I'm executing a script from the JavaScriptExecutor in Webdriver.  Forgot to mention that in my question.  I couldn't get yours to work until I removed the ">".  Then it seemed to work.  So I'll give biziclop +1 since I stole the beginning from him.  Do you know why the ">" doesn't work?  Could it be my version of jQuery?  I'm using 1.5.1.

Comment: here's the code I used: long pageCountText = (long)Element.GetLongValueFromJQuery(driver, "return $('#resultsContainer .pagination').first().children('span').length");

Comment: I'll upvote anyone's comment that knows why ">" didn't work.  In the mean time, I'll keep this unanswered to get more views

Comment: `#resultsContainer > * > .pagination` should work. `>` is the direct child selector ( http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/ )

Answer (score 2):

```
var spans = [];

$('#resultsContainer span').parent()
// OR $('#resultsContainer .pagination')

.each(function(){
  spans.push({
    parent: this,
    spanCount: $(this).children('span').length
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var pages = [];
$("#resultsContainer .pagination").each(function(index){
           pages.push($(this).children("span").length);  
});
$("body").append(pages.toString());
```

will get the length of each one, and put it in an array for your viewing pleasure.

Comment: +1 ... this is good info!  Didn't know about the push function